# mysql query to fetch data from database and display it in the form of stacked bar graph using php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, html5-canvas

Hi guys I have Google to get answer for the above question but I got the answer for displaying the plain bar graph one but not stacked bar graph.
My problem is I have to display the stacked bar graph based on the number of count of different categories for example the number of login to the site, reset password, chats etc.And I have to use plugin for displaying of graph.
I would request you guys to please suggest me some thing on this.As I'm new to php.
Thanks in advance guys

Comment: You are not telling us enough here.What graphing library are using using? Can you show code examples for where you are having problems? Can you show your DB schema and example for what you are trying to query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the question (a good one)

SELECT   `category`, COUNT(`category`) 
    FROM     users
    GROUP BY `category`
    ORDER BY `category`

This displays the total number of hits for each category.  In javascript I use AJAX call to execute the php - mysql, then return the array of counts back to the javascript to display the stack graph.

Comment: @Mike Brant    My Db structure has id ,date,count,category,hit_success and hit_failure based on this
If total count is 100 ,this count come from number of hits of a category,here category is reset password, login and so on.
If reset password have 70 hits per day,and login also have 30 hits on the same day then i have to write a query to take a total number of count and display it in the form of stacked bar graph.

Please help to write a mysql query to take total count and display it using any js plugin.

Comment: thanks for your query will try it out and let you know soon

Comment: @ storkmanI executed the query given by you I got the total number of hits of that particular categories,but I need to display the total number of hits of particular categories in a particular date ,for example 1)If there are hits for webtext,resetpwd and so on in a particular date for example on 31 march 2015 i have to display it in stalked bar graph format ,by displaying date at x axis and count at y axis.Please help me to do this thanks

Comment: @ storkman I executed the recent query posted by you,Im getting category   based on the user_id,instead i need to display total number of count of all the categories in a single date.Here I have to display the statistics report of the categories at a particular date.For Example, if reset password/login/webchat hav taken place in a single date several number of times ,here i have to consider the total count of individual category at a particular date and display in a form of stacked bar graph.Please suggest me on this

Comment: Note:where id is auto incremented

Comment: @user3753211, I think this is what you want, in the SELECT statement, you should have "where date = $date", $date is a php variable that should contain data that is in the same format that will match the data in the date field on your db table.  I am just recommending getting the right category data.  I do not have experience with javascript stacked bar graph code.

Answer (score 0):

I executed this code on my system, just substitute "where user_id = 36" for "where date = 31032015" (whatever date format), and change the table "users" to your table name.

```
$template2=mysql_query("SELECT  category, COUNT(category) FROM users where user_id = 36
GROUP BY category ORDER BY category ");
while($template=mysql_fetch_array($template2)){

echo "<tr><td>{$template['COUNT(category)']}  {$template['category']}</td></tr>";
}
```